# DataGridView returning Null in cell while trying to display images in datagrid cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two images in solution explorer at this location -

*~/Images/Active.jpg* & *~/Images/Inactive.jpg*

I want to display these images in my gridview cell depending upon the cell value i.e "Active" or "Inactive".

What I have tried so far is given below:

Gridview code in page source file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound1"   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"  >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="ServerName" SortExpression="ServerName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Application" HeaderText="Application" SortExpression="Application" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Instance" HeaderText="Instance" SortExpression="Instance" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Environment" HeaderText="Environment" SortExpression="Environment" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Image ID="imgID" imageurl="" runat="server" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>                 

            </Columns>
```

Code behind .aspx.cs file:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {               

                if (row.Cells[4].Text == "Active")
                {
                    Image img = (Image)row.FindControl("imgID");
                    img.ImageUrl= "";
                }
                else
                {
                    Image img = (Image)row.FindControl("imgID");
                    img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Inactive.jpeg";
                }
            }
```

Please note, I can not use rowdatabound. I have written above code in one of function where I am checking some stuff and updating cell values as Active or Inactive.

The problem arising is that DataGrid's Cell returning null value for images.

Please suggest solution to solve this.

Comment: Why do u assign empty - `img.ImageUrl= "";` for Active? It should be `"~/Images/Inactive.jpeg";`?

Comment: Why cant you use row Data Bound event ?

Comment: @KarthickRaju , that was bymistakely empty. but even if i put url there it is not working.

Comment: @Saurabh, i have already used databound event where i am displaying grid with some formatting like cell spanning for same values in rows. and i have written this code in the function which i am calling in databound itself after gridview formatting is done.

Comment: So what this code is doing anything or any error is coming ? whats the result of debugging ?

Comment: @Saurabh, debug shows error as img is getting null at first line itself here Image img = (Image)row.FindControl("imgID");

Comment: In your html Markup set a dummy image url to imageurl="Set Something here"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {               
            Image img = (Image)row.FindControl("imgID");

            if (img!=null)
            {
                img.ImageUrl= (row.Cells[4].Text == "Active") ? "~/Images/Active.jpg" : "~/Images/Inactive.jpg";
            }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your ImageURL using ternary operator:

```
ImageURL='<%# Eval("Status") == "Active" ? "~/Images/Active.jpg" : "~/Images/Inactive.jpg" %>'
```

Note: `Status` is a value from your datasource.

---

Or, you can done same thing in your RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgID");

        img.ImageURl = (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "Active") ? "~/Images/Active.jpg" : "~/Images/Inactive.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not storing values into database. I am checking server connections and if it is active then showing gridview cell active for that server.

Comment: but this `row.Cells[4].Text` code means you should have to bind cell value first otherwise it will be empty/null.

Comment: yes row.cells[4].text is having "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE"  and i can see in debug when it check condition whether cell text is having active or inactive. it works properly. but  after this line when i check img value in debug it shows as null  Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgID");

Comment: This is because you are binding URL dynamically so remove `imageurl=""` from image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers. I solved issue with below change. its working fine now. :

```
 if (answer.Contains("INACTIVE"))
                        {

                            row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("<img src='Images/Inactive.jpg'; height='30' width='30' />");


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("<img src='Images/Active.jpg'; height='30' width='30' />");

                        }
```